# VSTest.Console.exe run all the test projects in a solution using VS2013

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2013, command-line, nunit, vstest

I'm planing to use the vsTest to run all test projects under a solution without having to know the project name and location
In the documentation I found

```
/Tests[testsName]
```

Is there any way to do this with vstest or any other tool. vmdi is not supported by vs2013 and I can't change how solutions by adding vmdi file. I'm looking into NUint alos

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried NUnit console passing in your solution file (SLN)? It is a bit buggy, but may work depending on your solution.